# Can I add the VGA port to a ThinkCentre M90q Tiny?

Tags: vga

I didn't realize it wasn't included when I bought it and now I need to add it. I know I can use an HDMI to VGA dongle, but this is to be integrated into another product.  I prefer to not use a dongle.

Comment: Manufacturer's site says it's optional. Why not ask them if they sell a retrofit version or will swap the machine you just got for one that does? https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/desktops-and-all-in-ones/thinkcentre/m-series-tiny/ThinkCentre-M90q/p/WMD00000418

Answer (score 0):

I found this post elseware:  Re: ThingCentre M720q Serial Port
2019-12-11, 13:11 PM
Thanks for your reply. However, I have found the part myself:
Lenovo Part Number: 04X2733
Name: Fru, 50mm Com2 cable w/levelshift

The name is a bit misleading but it works as I thought. You plug it into the Header on the Mainboard and screw the connector into the back. (Even works with a SATA SSD)
I am assuming the card would work perfectly too, especially when you need two Serial ports.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkCentre-A-E-M-S-Series/ThingCentre-M720q-Serial-Port/m-p/4550724